# RubyOnRails Custom SQL Query in Ransack gem Advanced Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

[Click on image to see view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKIB8.png)

Ransack generated following query `SELECT "sheets".* FROM "sheets" WHERE ("sheets"."id" > 5)`
but I want to implement formula in query `SELECT "sheets".* FROM "sheets" WHERE (((score1 + score2)/2) > 5)`  Basically I want to compare formulas instead of attributes

Comment: Do you need ransack for this? `Sheet.where("(score1+score2)/2 > 5")` Active Record gets the job done.

Comment: yes because I need to make these requests from the frontend lets say I want an average > 5 how can I send Query from frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this You would need to implement a custom [ransacker](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers).

Something like

```
class Sheet < ApplicationRecord

  ransacker :average_score do |parent|
    (parent.table[:score1] + parent.table[:score2]) / 2
  end
end
```

Then you can use general ransack syntax. e.g. `average_score_gt` or using the more advanced version ( I believe)

```
Sheet.ransack(
  conditions: [{
    attributes: ['average_score'],
    predicate_name: 'gt',
    values: [5]
  }]
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working great with only one problem , it is evaluating score2/2 first , but I want to evaluate (score1 + score2)/2 . how can I make it evaluate addition first?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `:average_score` could be shortened to `(parent.table[:score1] + parent.table[:score2]) / 2` amusing `parent.table[:score1]` is an [`Arel::Attributes::Attribute`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Attributes/Attribute) instance.

Comment: @3limin4t0r excellent suggestion and no you are not wrong and additionally that creates the grouping I just added. I am so used to use Arel objects directly for other things that sometimes I overlook the more obvious solutions. Updated accordingly.

Comment: @3limin4t0r and engineersmnky Thank you , Any Docs you could suggest to me because I need more functionality from Arel?

Comment: Like Associations from attributes of Another Table, or  In the Same Table but attributes at different TimeStamp

Comment: @RatnarajSukale 1) [Arel Docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel); 2) I am not sure I understand the question; 3) if you have a separate instance/question you need addressed that you cannot otherwise resolve I would recommend opening a new question.

Comment: okay , now that I know it is done with Arel , I will check docs , and if not resolved would create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using ActiveRecord. I would prefer getting the user-selected values from params.

params:

```
 { filters: [{column: "id", operator: ">", value: 5}] }
```

With this, you can construct the condition in the backend.

```
condition =  ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql('id > 5')
```

Then you can pass this to your query.

```
Sheet.where(condition)
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want comparison directly on the column, I want do calculation on one or more columns and then compare that calculation

Comment: @RatnarajSukale What kind of calculation? can you share the table schema and also a sample query that you trying to construct?

Comment: SELECT "sheets".* FROM "sheets" WHERE (((score1 + score2)/2) > 5)   this is the rough query i am trying to perform . score1 and score2 are attributes in sheets model so want to perform calculation on these to columns (avg in this case). and give user form to select  ">"  "<"  "="  and number to compare it with